# vmware-fusion: How Clones affects Windows Licenses

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx, vmware-fusion

I am considering an upgrade to vmware-fusion 6.

I would like to do the following:

1. Install windows 7 as a Fusion VM, call it base, and leave it alone.
2. Create a clone of base and install IE 7
3. Create a clone of base and install IE 8
4. Create a clone of base and install IE 9
5. Proceed with testing such that I never run base or any of the clones
   at the same time.

As long as I never run the machines at the same time I do not think I am violating any of MS license agreements.  It is no different than if I took a backup of the machine and restored it.

Will I need more than one Windows 7 license to do this?

Would switching to parallels or virtualbox be a solution?

I have sw other than IE that I want to do this with, so I am looking for a generic solution, not one specific to IE.

I am using "clone" as a generic term.  If there are ways to accomplish what I am asking such as using linked clones or copying files on the harddrive, then I am open to those solutions as well.

Comment: Yes, you need multiple licenses. No, it's not the same as restoring a backup.

Comment: For the benefit of others that may stumble on this questions hoping to find an answer: this question was marked as duplicate, when really it should have been marked as inappropriate for serverfault.  The powers that be have decided that licensing questions are not appropriate for serverfault.  I can understand why they have this policy.